# How to solve $32^x - 8 = 2 \cdot 4^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am given the following equation to solve

> $$32^x - 8 = 2 \cdot 4^x$$

which one can simplyfy to $$2^{5x}-2^3 = 2^{2x+1}$$

where do we go from here? If we had something like $$2^{2x} - 5 \cdot 2^x + 6 = 0$$

we could convert it to a quadratic, but not in this case.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This leads to a difficult polynomial equation. Are you sure about the coefficients ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, exactly my conclusion. Yes I am sure.

Comment: Where is that coming from ?

Comment: From a colleague's material. He had that on a 10th grade, no calc, test.

Comment: Are you familiar with the rational roots theorem and have you tried any polynomial long division to find a factor?

Comment: @Diehardwalnut I am actually but I am trying to figure out why my colleague would have this on a 10th grade test. I am guessing the negative sign should be a times sign, that would make the quetion 10th grade level.

Comment: I'm thinking so too, the only real solution isn't a rational root as found by wolfram.

Comment: @Diehardwalnut thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still convert it into a polynomial, since

$$2^{5x} - 8 = 2\cdot 2^{2x}$$

converts to

$$y^5-8=2y^2$$

if you introduce $y=2^x$.

Comment: but you need a software (calculator) to solve that, correct?

Comment: @bru1987 Yes, the solution to this equation can only be calculated numerically, but there's really no going around this fact. Any solution of your original equation would also give rise to a solution of this equation, after all.

Comment: thank you for the answer.